# Why Elements is empty?

Tags: java, jsoup

I use JSoup for the first time. so i'm not familiar with JSoup. I already read 'COOKBOOk'. But still i don't know why that Elements still empty. am i missing something?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://sports.news.naver.com/sports/" + 
    "index.nhn?category=baseball.html").get();
        Elements teams= doc.select("td.t_name");
        Elements wins= doc.select("td.win");
        System.out.println(teams.isEmpty());
        System.out.println(wins.isEmpty());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because there is no "td.t_name" and "td.win" in the document.
You should make sure that the document you get form http://sports.news.naver.com/sports/index.nhn?category=baseball.html
contain the data you want to select.

As far as I debugged into your code, I didn't see any "td.win" or "td.t_name" in the document.

Note that data loaded in via AJAX will not be downloaded by JSoup.

Comment: I find why this doesn't work. it's because last '.html' lead me totally diffrent page. it resolved thanks.